# Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise Banner Slider Issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2, knockout

I am experiencing that the `default banner slider` is not compatible with the `mobile` devices in `Magento 2.3.2` enterprise version. Slider is working fine for the desktop. Can anyone help me to understand the best approach to fix it ?

Comment: What JS library r u using if you are using slick make sure you set this option true - mobileFirst: true

Comment: I am using Magento commerce 2.3.2 (enterprise version) default pagebuilder feature on the home page, it's also using slick with pagebuilder. how to fix this issue.